# Maven API for C#

Tags: c#, maven, maven-2, maven-3

Is the API for Maven available in C#? I have a C# application with which is I access Maven, but does it via Process and cmd.exe at the moment.

All my searches just give me how to use Maven to build C# projects.

Something similar to this but for C#:
http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.Net Maven Plugin`

Link : http://doodleproject.sourceforge.net/mavenite/dotnet-maven-plugin/

Or you can also use  `NPanday`

Link : http://incubator.apache.org/npanday/

Comment: That's not what I am looking for, I am looking for a C# equivalent of an API to interact with Maven similar to this: http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html